# AppCompatActivity fails to call onCreate (Xamarin)

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I'm trying to create an activity, as a subclass of AppCompatActivity, and I'm getting the following:`JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: can't call void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(bundle) on instance of md548d3f6682eaea9ae319016469055fba4.MainActivity
04-13 04:58:31.878 F/art     ( 4356): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]     in call to CallNonvirtualVoidMethodA`
AppCompat library version is 23.0.0.1, exactly the same as designer.

Has anyone come across this? I must be doing something extremely wrong, any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Here is the code causing the crash:

```
[Activity(Label = "Main", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{


    protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

     }
}
```

Comment: can you paste the code? What you are doing?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs into the same issue: it was theme related, I just added `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"` to the application key in manifest.